# Lambda for multiple conditional functions in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda

Assuming I'm dealing with this dataframe:

| Total | Retired | Cancelled | Remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 20 | 70 |
| 150 | 160 | 30 | -40 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

where

```
df['Remaining'] = df['Total'] - df['Retired'] - df['Cancelled']
```

My desired output should be like this from previous dataframe (to manually revise the negative ones in 'Remaining' to zeros):

| Total | Retired | Cancelled | Remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 20 | 70 |
| 190 | 160 | 30 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried these lines, but it returns error. What did I do wrong?

```
df['Total'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['Retired'] + x['Cancelled']) if x['Remaining'] < 0 else x['Total'])
```

(and do the previous calculation again for final output)

```
df['Remaining'] = df['Total'] - df['Retired'] - df['Cancelled']
```

Comment: please provide the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create your desired output example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Total': [100, 120, 137, 210, 111],
                 'Retired': [20, 90, 60, 110,  170],
                 'Cancelled': [70, 10, 80, 50, 0]})

df = df.assign(Remaining = df['Total'] - df['Retired'] - df['Cancelled'])

df['Remaining'] = df['Remaining'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < 0 else x)
df['Total'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Total'] if x['Remaining'] > 0 else x['Retired'] + x['Cancelled'], axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `axis=1` to `apply` so operation is row-wise. Otherwise, your `x` is a column of the dataframe.

But you can also do without apply:

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].where(df['Remaining'] >= 0, df['Retired'] + df['Cancelled'])
```